# Weird green window border in SFML Release compilation

Tags: c++, sfml

Seems a bit weird to me. I'm creating a simple snake game using SFML (not important), when I run the app in release mode I get such a strange green border. It does not appear in debug tho.

What is it and how can I get rid of this?

[image: weird border around my window in SFML release]

Comment: Who knows. Maybe if you posted a [mcve] we'd have a fighting chance.

Comment: I don't think it comes from code or sth, just wanted to know if this is a known issue.
If it is not, then maybe I did sth strange unconsciously.

Comment: Looks more like some kind of third party tool on your end highlighting the window outlines for whatever reason.

Comment: Yeah. Checked if it was antivirus – it was not.
I wonder why this appears only in release compilation. Can it be a VS setting? Or SFML setting?

Comment: @GameDevMike Which is your antivirus? According with [this](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/280084-strange-frame-around-all-windows.html) post, it seems to be related with Comodo Antivirus...

Comment: yeah, it most probably is (that's the av I use); I was not aware that time